# .NET GDI+ Invert Text

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, gdi+

What is the best method of inverting text using .NET and GDI+.  By invert, I mean draw with different background/foreground colors.  The term best is subjective, but I would define it to mean speed, lines of code, easiest (i.e. is there just one function call I can make?).

C# or VB.NET is fine.

Comment: Invert how? Mirror? Painting with inverted color?

Comment: Best? In what way? Quality of result? Speed? Minimal resource usage? Something else?

Comment: What does 'inverting' text mean: do you mean drawing it with different foreground+background colors? And do you control/write the code which uses GDI to draw the text?

Comment: Additionally, "inverting" can be any of: inversion of colors, writing the text back to front, writing the text upside down. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

You can `FillRectangle` with `Brushes.Black`, then `DrawString` with `Brushes.White`.
Depending on your scenario, you can get the size of the rectangle by calling `MeasureString`.

Comment: How does this compare to other methods in terms of speed, lines of code, ease of implementation?

Comment: @TextInverter: There aren't other methods. This is how you draw white text on a black background.  If you already have a black background, you can skip the first step.

Comment: Could I use a GraphicsPath.  If so, what advantage does it provide?

Comment: Yes.  You could also use Direct3D.  Both would be utterly pointless.

Comment: What does a GraphicsPath have to do with Direct3D?

Comment: Nothing.  They are two different utterly pointless alternatives.

Comment: Ok.  How would I use a GraphicsPath?

Comment: @@TextInverter Don't use GraphicsPath because it's not relevent for drawing text.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are asking about mirroring the text. Just use this code in form onPaint method

```
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawString("String on form", Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);

        // here Im mirror graphics
        g.MultiplyTransform(new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 40));

        // Drawing mirror text
        g.DrawString("String on form", Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);

        // returning graphics to normal state
        g.ResetTransform();
```